# How do I display elements in a template that have foreignkey relationships?

Tags: python, django, django-models, view

I am trying to display the video urls for each of the videos a user has saved as part of a playlist.  The user is able to save multiple playlists as well (the first line in the view displays all of the playlists).  I am struggling to figure out how to show the videos in each of the playlists though.  Any advice?

## views.py

```
def profile(request):
    playlist = UserPlaylist.objects.filter(profile=request.user)
    
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/profiles.html', {'playlist':playlist},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## models.py

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    playlist = models.CharField('Playlist', max_length = 2000, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.playlist
    
class Video(models.Model):
    video_url = models.URLField('Link to video', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.video_url

class UserPlaylist(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User)
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.playlist)

class Videoplaylist(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video)
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(UserPlaylist)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.playlist)
```

## template: profiles.html

```
{% for feed in playlist %}

    {{feed}}
    
    <br>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign key relationships can be accessed using `.` to span relationship

`{{ feed.playlist.playlist }}`

`{{ feed.profile.username }}`

since this is a queryset of `UserPlaylist` objects they have either a `profile` or `playlist` property.

Be careful though! I do believe this does a seperate query each time you access a foreign relationship.  I'm not sure though but it is worth checking out on debug toolbar or something.

according to Victor 'Chris' Cabral you can span relationships backwards using

`[model_you_want_to_span]_set.all`

you coudl also do this lookup in your view using

`vpls = Videoplaylist.objects.filter(playlist__profile=request.user)`

```
{% for feed in playlist %}    
    {{feed}}
    {% for vpl in feed.videoplaylist_set.all %}    
      {{ vpl.video.video_url }}    
    {% endfor %}    
    <br>    
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you know how would I access the videos in the each of the userplaylists?

Comment: {% for feed in playlist.videoplaylist_set.all %}
    [model]_set.all will follow the relationship "backwards".
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/
{% endfor %}

Comment: I'm using {{feed.videoplaylist_set.all}} but I'm not able to display the video urls.  I tried {{feed.videoplaylist_set.videos.all}} but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: @sharataka gave example, it would be very helpful to do some tutorials and read django book on how to query models.  Also i think this will do a ton of queries, probably good idea to profile it